# Depth-first search never reaching goal state

Tags: c#, search

I was studying search algorithms and wanted to solve the [missionaries and cannibals](http://www.aiai.ed.ac.uk/~gwickler/missionaries.html) problem in order to practice. However, my code never provides a solution. At first, I thought this was because I had recurring states, causing an infinite loop, so I added a state history to make sure states weren't being repeated. However, this still has not worked.

Below is the code I have written. I am using vectors to represent the states of the missionaries, cannibals and the boat and the children of the nodes get added if they pass a check that checks if the move is within the range (0,0,0) and (3,3,1).

I have tried stepping through the code but since the tree is fairly large I can only keep track of so many things, so I have a hard time seeing the fault in my code.

This was written in Visual Studio as a console program.

Vector3 class

```
public class Vector3
{
    public int m;
    public int c;
    public int b;
    public Vector3(int M, int C, int B)
    {
        m = M;
        c = C;
        b = B;
    }
    public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        Vector3 p = obj as Vector3;
        if ((System.Object)p == null)
            return false;

        return (m == p.m) && (c == p.c) && (b == p.b);
    }
}
```

Node class

```
public class Node
{
    public Vector3 State;
    public Node(Vector3 st)
    {
        State = st;
    }
}
```

My Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.DFS(new Node(new Vector3(3, 3, 1)));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    List<Vector3> History = new List<Vector3>();
    Vector3[] Operators = new Vector3[]
    {
        new Vector3(1,0,1),
        new Vector3(2,0,1),
        new Vector3(0,1,1),
        new Vector3(0,2,1),
        new Vector3(1,1,1),
    };

    public bool TryMove(Vector3 current, Vector3 toApply, bool substract)
    {
        if (substract)
        {
            if (current.c - toApply.c < 0 || current.m - toApply.m < 0 || current.b - toApply.b < 0 || (current.c - toApply.c) > (current.m - toApply.m))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (current.c + toApply.c > 3 || current.m + toApply.m > 3 || current.b + toApply.b > 1 || (current.c + toApply.c) > (current.m + toApply.m))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else return true;
        }
    }
    public void DFS(Node n)
    {
        Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
        stack.Push(n);
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {

            Node curNode = stack.Pop();
            if (History.Contains(curNode.State))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                History.Add(curNode.State);
                if (curNode.State == new Vector3(0, 0, 0))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Solution found.");
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (curNode.State.b == 0) //Boat is across the river
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
                        {
                            if (TryMove(curNode.State, Operators[x], false))
                            {
                                stack.Push(new Node(new Vector3(curNode.State.m + Operators[x].m, curNode.State.c + Operators[x].c, curNode.State.b + Operators[x].b)));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else //Boat == 1
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
                        {
                            if (TryMove(curNode.State, Operators[x], true))
                            {
                                stack.Push(new Node(new Vector3(curNode.State.m - Operators[x].m, curNode.State.c - Operators[x].c, curNode.State.b - Operators[x].b)));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("No solution found.");
        return;
    }
}
```

My code keeps hitting the 'No solution found' block. When I remove the history I keep infinite looping between states (3,3,1) and (2,2,1) and get an OutOfMemoryException at the 2 gigabyte mark, so I'm not even sure about keeping track of history anymore.

What steps should I take in order to implement the DFS in the context of the problem correctly, given the code I provided above?

Comment: What did you learn while debugging line by line, especially in the infinite loop?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but I learned that recurring states were a big problem using depth-first search and that the tree being generated can be incredibly large. Keeping track of history, I get no solution. Not keeping track of history, I loop infinitely (and run out of memory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm is fine. The problem is that you used `==` operator in `curNode.State == new Vector3(0, 0, 0);` line. In C#, by default, `==` compares objects by reference, so this condition will always return false. Either use `node.State.Equals(new Vector3(0, 0, 0))` or override `==` operator to use your `Equals` method.

See [MSDN Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.90).aspx) on custom comparison in C#.

Comment: Incredible! It finds the solution now. I thought I was being fancy overriding equality operators and all! Anyhow, thank you for a good quality answer and reminding me (and hopefully others) of this gotcha.